# SIP call video m line rejected with port as 0

Tags: video-streaming, sip, sdp

What are all the reasons,
so that remote can reject video m-line as 0

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean on "reject" and why do you wish to send port 0?

Port 0 in SDP media was used in the past to signale call hold, but nowadays should not be used anymore. For this now you have the a=inactive, a=recvonly, a=sendonly, a=sendrecv SDP options, so port number set to 0 is actually meaningless now and some implementations might choose to reject the call if set so.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264#section-6

```
   To reject an offered
   stream, the port number in the corresponding stream in the answer
   MUST be set to zero.  Any media formats listed are ignored.
```

So, the remote site simply does not wish to send or receive video - whether by missing support or configuration.